# Evaluating $1+\frac1{2+\frac1{4+\frac1{8+\cdots}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

Evaluate:
$$S=1+ \frac{1}{2+ \dfrac{1}{4+ \dfrac{1}{8+ \dfrac{1}{16 +\cdots} }} }$$

## What have I done, so far?

Nothing, couldn't think of a way to solve it. But I know it is around 1.46.

I want to solve it myself, so hint on how to solve will be sufficent.

Comment: How do you know it is around $1.46$?

Comment: @SarGe - Partial sums...

Comment: just curious, where did you get this problem?

Comment: @HariRamakrishnanSudhakar - Don't remember, it was in my notebook, for a some time.

Comment: @Blue - The link does answer my question (somewhat).If there is no closed-form, I have to find one. Thanks.

Comment: I closed the question.